# Format improvement for step-by-step solution to cubic equations

Tags: amsmath, highlighting, boldmath, callout

Within `\amsmath` and `\tasks`, the step-by-step solution process to find the 3 roots for a cubic equation is provided.

Request your assistance with 2 issues:

1. Decrease horiz space between the 2 cube roots in each problem to approx 2-3 mm:

[image]

2. Insert call outs (left and right cols)  to identify the first factor that yields a root. Also, **bold the yellow highlighted factor**.

[image]

Thank you! mwe below

````
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{framed} %box para
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

%\usepackage{bm}%bold equation
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % removes paragraph indentation

\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algegra II: Assignment: 10-C Solving Polynomial Equations}
       {}
       {Due 03/12/2023} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
  %\makebox[\textwidth]%{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}\par
  \vspace{4mm}
  \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule}{
    \textbf {Solve each polynomial equation by factoring. Find all real and/or  imaginary/complex roots. Simplify answers.}
    %\par
    %\bigskip

  }}}\par
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}
\setlength{\jot}{1em}
%define highlighting

\newcommand{\hll}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{$\displaystyle #1$}}

\begin{document}
\pagetop

\settasks{
    after-item-skip=3em,    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=2em,
    item-indent=3em,
    label=(\arabic*),
    column-sep=2em
}
\begin{tasks}(2)
%Prob #1
\task \(\begin{aligned}[t]
&x^3-216=0 \\
& \hspace{2em}\begin{aligned}[t]
&\sqrt[3]{x^3} =3
&\sqrt[3]{216} =6\\
&\hll {(x-6)}(x^2+6x+6^2)\\
&\hll{(x-6)}(x^2+6x+36)\\
&a = 1; b = 6; c = 36\\
&x=\frac{-(b)\pm\sqrt{(b^2)-4(a)(c)}}{2(a)}\\
&x=\frac{-(6)\pm\sqrt{(6^2)-4(1)(36)}}{2(1)}\\
&x=\frac{-6\pm\sqrt{-144}}{2}\\
&x=\frac{-(6)\pm\sqrt{(6^2)-4(1)(36)}}{2(1)}\\
&x=\frac{-6\pm\sqrt{-108}}{2}\\
&x=\frac{-6\pm 6i\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
&x=\frac{2(-3\pm 3i\sqrt{3})}{2}\\
&x=\-3\pm 3i\sqrt{3}&x=6\\
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}\)
%Problem #2
\task \(\begin{aligned}[t]
&8x^3 +125 \\
& \hspace{2em}\begin{aligned}[t]
&\sqrt[3]{8x^3} =2x
&\sqrt[3]{125} =5\\
&\hll{(2x+5)}(4x^2-10x+5^2)\\
&\hll{(2x+5)}(4x^2-10x+25)\\
&a = 4; b = -10; c = 25\\
&x=\frac{-(b)\pm\sqrt{(b^2)-4(a)(c)}}{2(a)}\\
&x=\frac{-(-10)\pm\sqrt{(-10^2)-4(4)(25)}}{2(4)}\\
&x=\frac{10\pm\sqrt{-300}}{8}\\
&x=\frac{10\pm 10i\sqrt{3}}{8}\\
&x=\frac{2(5\pm 5i\sqrt{3})}{8}\\
&x=\frac{5\pm 5i\sqrt{3})}{4}&x=-\frac{-5}{2}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}\)
%Problem #3

\end{tasks}
\end{document}```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's go in parts:

1. For simple spacing, we can use the command `\quad` or `\qquad` to maintain a certain standardization in the spacing, in your case, using `\qquad` is the best thing to do.
2. To create the yellow box with a warning box I made a new command that assigns two entries: `\callout{#1}{#2}`. The first entry `#1` is the term of the equation that will be highlighted in yellow, while the second entry `#2` is the rest of the equation that will not be highlighted. An important thing to comment on is the need for an instruction, in this case `[2.2em]` before the line break. It will become clearer by exemplifying it.

### Packages

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{framed} % box para
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts} % To create the call out boxes
```

### The new command

```
\newcommand*{\callout}[2]{\hspace{-5em}
\tikz[baseline=(X)] \node[shape = rectangle callout, 
    fill=white, 
    draw= black, 
    minimum width=4.5em,
    rounded corners,
    callout relative pointer={(+0.55,-0.45)}, 
    font = {\sffamily},
    ] (X) {${\scriptsize\begin{matrix}\textrm{1st root/} \\ \textrm{solution}\end{matrix}}$};%
\tikz[baseline=(X.base)] \node[rectangle, fill=yellow, inner sep=1mm] (Y) at ([yshift = -2.2em]X) {$#1$};%
\tikz[baseline=(X.base)] \node[] at (Y.east) {$#2$};%
 }
```

### The new command without vertical spacing instrunction

```
 \begin{tasks}(2)
 % Problem 1:
 \task \(
 \begin{aligned}[t]
    & x^3-216 = 0 \\
    & \hspace{2em}
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        & \sqrt[3]{x^3} = 3 \qquad \sqrt[3]{216} = 6 \\
        & \hll{(x-6)}(x^2+6x+6^2) \\%[-2.2em]
        % Do not space here:        ^
        & \callout{(x-6)}{(x^2+6x+36)} \\
    \end{aligned}
 \end{aligned}
 \)
 \end{tasks}
```

With this code, the output have these whitespace:
[image]

### The new command within vertical spacing instrunction

But, if we include these instrunction:

```
 \begin{tasks}(2)
 % Problem 1:
 \task \(
 \begin{aligned}[t]
    & x^3-216 = 0 \\
    & \hspace{2em}
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        & \sqrt[3]{x^3} = 3 \qquad \sqrt[3]{216} = 6 \\
        & \hll{(x-6)}(x^2+6x+6^2) \\[-2.2em]
        % Do not space here:        ^
        & \callout{(x-6)}{(x^2+6x+36)} \\
    \end{aligned}
 \end{aligned}
 \)
 \end{tasks}
```

We obtain this:
[image]

### A little comment about this new command

I included a comment to not space the double bar `\\` and the instrunction `[-2.2em]`, this is because the these instrunction don't works with this space.

### The complete code

To conclude, I will post all the code and the respective output:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{framed} %box para
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}

\newcommand*{\callout}[2]{\hspace{-5em}
    \tikz[baseline=(X)] \node[shape = rectangle callout, 
        fill=white, 
        draw= black, 
        minimum width=4.5em,
        rounded corners,
        callout relative pointer={(+0.55,-0.45)}, 
        font = {\sffamily},
        ] (X) {${\scriptsize\begin{matrix}\textrm{1st root/} \\ \textrm{solution}\end{matrix}}$};%
    \tikz[baseline=(X.base)] \node[rectangle, fill=yellow, inner sep=1mm] (Y) at ([yshift = -2.2em]X) {$#1$};%
    \tikz[baseline=(X.base)] \node[] at (Y.east) {$#2$};%
}

%\usepackage{bm}%bold equation
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % removes paragraph indentation

\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Assignment: 10-C Solving Polynomial Equations}
       {}
       {Due 03/12/2023} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
  %\makebox[\textwidth]%{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}\par
  \vspace{4mm}
  \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule}{
    \textbf {Solve each polynomial equation by factoring. Find all real and/or  imaginary/complex roots. Simplify answers.}
    %\par
    %\bigskip

  }}}\par
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}
\setlength{\jot}{1em}
%define highlighting

\newcommand{\hll}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{$\displaystyle #1$}}

\begin{document}
\pagetop

\settasks{
    after-item-skip=3em,    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=2em,
    item-indent=3em,
    label=(\arabic*),
    column-sep=2em
}

\begin{tasks}(2)
    % Problem 1:
    \task \(
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        & x^3-216 = 0 \\
        & \hspace{2em}
        \begin{aligned}[t]
            & \sqrt[3]{x^3} = 3 \qquad \sqrt[3]{216} = 6 \\
            & \hll{(x-6)}(x^2+6x+6^2) \\[-2.2em]
            % Do not space here:        ^
            & \callout{(x-6)}{(x^2+6x+36)} \\
            & a = 1; b = 6; c = 36 \\
            & x = \frac{-(b)\pm\sqrt{(b^2)-4(a)(c)}}{2(a)} \\
            & x = \frac{-(6)\pm\sqrt{(6^2)-4(1)(36)}}{2(1)} \\
            & x = \frac{-6\pm\sqrt{-144}}{2} \\
            & x = \frac{-(6)\pm\sqrt{(6^2)-4(1)(36)}}{2(1)} \\
            & x = \frac{-6\pm\sqrt{-108}}{2} \\
            & x = \frac{-6\pm 6i\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
            & x = \frac{2(-3\pm 3i\sqrt{3})}{2} \\
            & x = \-3\pm 3i\sqrt{3} \qquad x=6 \\
        \end{aligned}
    \end{aligned}
    \)
    % Problem #2
    \task 
    \(\begin{aligned}[t]
        & 8x^3 +125 \\
        & \hspace{2em}
        \begin{aligned}[t]
            & \sqrt[3]{8x^3} = 2x \qquad \sqrt[3]{125} = 5 \\
            & \hll{(2x+5)}(4x^2-10x+5^2) \\[-2.2em]
            & \callout{(2x+5)}{(4x^2-10x+25)} \\
            & a = 4; b = -10; c = 25 \\
            & x = \frac{-(b)\pm\sqrt{(b^2)-4(a)(c)}}{2(a)} \\
            & x = \frac{-(-10)\pm\sqrt{(-10^2)-4(4)(25)}}{2(4)} \\
            & x = \frac{10\pm\sqrt{-300}}{8} \\
            & x = \frac{10\pm 10i\sqrt{3}}{8} \\
            & x = \frac{2(5\pm 5i\sqrt{3})}{8} \\
            & x = \frac{5\pm 5i\sqrt{3})}{4} \qquad x=-\frac{-5}{2} \\
        \end{aligned}
    \end{aligned}
    \)
    % Problem 3
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: ....beautiful, just beautiful work! Can't wait to share with my students. Thanks also for being an excellent teacher and providing a detailed explanation of your code changes.

Comment: comment above was meant for you. One further question...could you please clarify your comment to "not space the double bar ```\\``` and the instrunction ```[-2.2em]```, this is because the these instrunction don't works with this space." Do you mean delete all the ```\\```? Muchas gracias!

Comment: If you use ```\\[-2.2em]``` in your code, it will work. However, if you write ```\\ [-2.2em]```, the LaTeX compiler will interpret ```[-2.2em]``` as plain text rather than an instruction. Therefore, you must use it without the space for it to work properly.

Comment: I can explain the reason to omit a space from `\\[-2.2em]`.  Originally, it didn't make any difference, but authors who needed to start a line with an expression in brackets kept getting error messages that they didn't understand.  Since lines starting with bracketed expressions apparently occurred more frequently than the need to adjust the vertical distance between lines, the condition with the space was changed to simply output what is in the brackets.  Thus if it is intended to change the distance, don't insert a space.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks much for your very helpful explainer.